# Python 3 psutil, extracting pid and name values?

Tags: windows, python-3.x, psutil

For Python 3.5 on Windows 7 64-bit and the psutil 5 library.

I'm confused as to how to properly access the name and pid information provided within each *class 'psutil.Process'* item returned by *psutil.process_iter()*.

The following code returns a *class 'generator'* object:

```
import psutil
curProcesses = psutil.process_iter()
```

A simple loop outputs each class *'psutil.Process'* object contained within that generator:

```
for eachProcess in curProcesses:
    print(eachProcess)
```

OUTPUT:

```
psutil.Process(pid=0, name='System Idle Process')
psutil.Process(pid=4, name='System')
          ... and so on ...
```

Now here's where I'm getting confused.

IF I modify the previous loop as follows, THEN I'll get an integer *pid* and a string *name*.

```
for eachProcess in curProcesses:
    # Observe the two different forms of access.
    print(eachProcess.pid)
    print(eachProcess.name())
```

OUTPUT:

```
0
System Idle Process
4
System
... and so on ...
```

The resulting integer and string are exactly what I want. However, after several experiments I can only get them IF:

- *eachProcess.pid* is NOT followed by parentheses ala *eachProcess.pid*. (Adding parentheses produces a *TypeError: 'int' object is not callable* exception.)
- *eachProcess.name* is followed by parentheses ala *eachProcess.name()*. (Removing the parentheses returns a *bound method Process.name* instead of the name as a string.)

Why do the two keyword-looking arguments *pid* and *name* behave differently? (I suspect I'm about to learn something very useful about Python 3 generator objects...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not much to it really: [`pid`](https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#psutil.Process.pid) is a read-only attribute (created with the [`@property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) decorator), and [`name()`](https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#psutil.Process.name) is a method, both of the [`Process`](https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#psutil.Process) class. Methods need parens to be called in order to return data, while attributes are accessed without them. [This bit of documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes) might be helpful. Also, if you find it helpful, you can see the difference in implementation between [`name()`](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/blob/master/psutil/__init__.py#L627) and [`pid`](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/blob/master/psutil/__init__.py#L604).

As far as *why* `pid` is a read-only attribute of `Process`, while a method `name()` needs to be called in order to get the process name, I am not sure. In fact, `pid` appears to be the only read-only attrubute on the process class, while all other information about the process instance is retrieved through method calls. Personally it seems inconsistent/non-standard to do it this way, but I assume that there is a good reason for this choice. I assume the main reason is so the PID cannot be changed accidentally since it is a crucial component. If the PID were a method instead of a read-only attribute, then `eachProcess.pid = 123` in your loop would change the method to the int `123`, while the  way it currently is, this attempted reassignment will raise an error instead, so that the PID is protected in a sense, while `eachProcess.name = 'foo'` will probably go by without raising an error.

Also, note that while they may look like keyword arguments in the way they appear in the string representations of `Process` class instances, `name()` and `pid` are not keyword arguments (although `pid` can be passed as a keyword argument when creating a `Process` instance, but that  is not what is happening here).

Comment: Is there a straightforward way to know that a not-really-keyword-argument returned in a generator object is a read-only attribute versus a method? Or must one go behind the figurative curtain and read the library's code? (Or experiment as I did until the generator object coughs up the desired information.)

Comment: @RBV your best bet is always going to be 1) read the documentation, and 2) experiment. I usually go with #2 first, and then #1 if I can't figure it out through experimentation - it is probably safer to do it the other way around though. Always best to read the documentation first. If the docs are good it should be clear whether something is a method or an attribute, what the return value is, what the arguments are, etc. The docs linked above for `psutil` do these things with regards to the properties you are interested in.

Comment: If an attribute it written as a method that takes no arguments, as opposed to a property, that probably means it potentially does a lot of work. The code for properties should be fairly light -- not much more than a regular instance attribute lookup. For example, for `name` on Windows the initial lookup has to iterate over a snapshot of information about all running processes on the system until it finds the current process, so it's implemented as a method call.

Answer (score 2):

I made `pid` a class attribute / property mainly for consistency with `subprocess.Popen.pid` and `multiprocessing.Process.pid` stdlib modules (also `threading.Thread.ident` comes to mind).

Also, it's something which does not require any calculation (contrarily from `name()`, `cmdline()` etc.) and it never changes, so something read-only made more sense to me at the time.

It's a property rather than a mere attribute just to error out in case the user tries to change/set it.